# que puedo cambiar, al cargar un xlsx a excel y si una celda tiene: ' marca error

Tags: php, mysql, excel

buen dia.
ya tengo la pagina creada y me carga bien mis archivos excel a mysql usando php, todo bien hasta ahi
pero cuando celda tiene el signo de '

hay error al insertar o actualizar la tabla. los archivos de excel me los mandan, yo los acomodo a mi formato de excel para subirlos.
se puede cambiar algo a la libreria de php, al codigo o simplemente les borro los '''' a las celdas.

esto es lo que tiene una celda que me da error:
**CABLE DE SEGURIDAD 7.6MTS MOD STEELBRAID 25'**

y si simplemente lo dejo asi:
**CABLE DE SEGURIDAD 7.6MTS MOD STEELBRAID 25**
si funciona. y me manda el error en la siguiemte celda que tenga '''

este es el error que sale:

> error al ACTUALIZAR datosYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'candado', existProd='100', existMinim='25',
>   precioComp='267.12', precioMay='274.' at line 1

Comment: A lo mejor digo una burrada, pero ¿te lo coge si el apóstrofe es doble? Es decir, en vez de `'` que haya `''`

Comment: si lo lee bien la celda con los ''. que raro, pero conun ' sigue batallando, entonces o los quito los ' o los pongo dobles ''. o q recomiendas

Comment: No es tan raro. De SQL sé poco, pero sí es cierto que el apóstrofe `'` lo utiliza como símbolo para separar criterios WHERE por ejemplo. Pero al ponerlo doble como `''`, entonces lo lee bien. Respecto a quitarlos o ponerlos dobles, todo depende de tus necesidades. Si no vas a necesitar mostrar nunca en ningún sitio el apóstrofe, entonces quítalo. Si tienes que mostrarlo (por ejemplo, hay apellidos ingleses que lo tienen), entonces úsalos dobles.

Comment: gracias, asi lo hare.
habia leido tambien. que si no me pongo listo. alguien que sepa algo de sql, puedo subir el xls y subir "codigo" que inserte o me altere mi bd. gracias

Answer (score 0):

ya se porque marca error, es porque es un inserccion SQL, y la forma de quitar ese error es con

```
$mysqli->real_escape_string( )
```

asi simplemente todo lo lee como caracteres inofencivos